# \newcommand and \renewcommand difficulty in class file

Tags: macros, document-classes

I am making an "Assignment" class file. One element of my class is not working correctly. I want to be able to input the assignment # in the latex file, using `\assigntitle{4}` and have a centered Assignment #4 printed at the top of the page. I use a `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` to implement this in the class file. Alas this portion is not working. I only get the predefined output from the `\newcommand` definition and not my value input from the latex file. I think it is because of a scoping issue, but I can't figure out how to get around it. I tried to use `\global\def\` but this didn't work. I think `\renewcommand` can't use this type of `\def`. If I am wrong, please inform me.

I have removed extraneous code (and yes I have tried it with only this code) from the full file, of which I show below.

```
\ProvidesClass{Assignment}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\newcommand{\@assignment}{Assignment \#}
\newcommand{\assigntitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\@assignment}{Assignment \#{#1}}}


\AtBeginDocument{%
    \centering \huge \upshape \@assignment \\
    \normalsize \normalfont \@date
    \bigskip
}

\endinput
```

example.tex

```
\documentclass[english]{Assignment}

\begin{document}

\assigntitle{4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would really help if you would post a `sample` file that uses this class.

Comment: Where do you make a call to `\assigntitle` in your main `.tex` document?

Comment: @Werner I have edited the question to show the usage. In order for the class to be used with Lyx, I think it has to be called after `begin{document}` ...at least that is where Lyx puts it.

Comment: @Michelle: Using LyX makes it clear now. I've suggested [an alternative definition of `\assigntitle` below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321454/5764), which might suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this implementation I'd suggest using `\assigntitle` not just to update some internal macro, but also to set the actual title:

```
\newcommand{\assigntitle}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
    \huge \upshape Assignment \# #1 \\
    \normalsize \normalfont \@date
  \end{center}
}
```

If you want to set a date other than `\today`, the you'd use

```
\date{January 1, 2001}
\assigntitle{4}
```

Comment: You mean I made it more complicated than it need be? :) This works nice.  I guess I was trying to have a default, but now that I think about it that could be dangerous (putting the wrong number on an assignment).

Comment: @Michelle: Since you most likely want to set the title when you set the assignment number, joining the definition seems appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

The basic problem is that `\@assignment` is used right at the start of the document body within `\AtBeginDocument`, so using `\assigntitle{4}` etc. after `\begin{document}` is ineffective, since the redefined `\@assignment` is never used then.

`\centering` should not occur outside of a group, so use `\begingroup...\endgroup`.

I suggest to use a pagestyle header (e.g. `fancyhdr`) rather which is updated, also using counters.

`Assignment.cls`

```
\ProvidesClass{Assignment}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\newcommand{\@assignment}{Assignment \#}
\newcommand{\assigntitle}[1]{\edef\@assignment{Assignment \#{#1}}}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup
  \centering 
  \huge \upshape \@assignment 
  \medskip

  \normalsize \normalfont \@date

  \bigskip

  \endgroup
}

\endinput
```

`driver.tex`

```
\documentclass{Assignment}


\assigntitle{4}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, this is very helpful. I now see why it wouldn't work. I can manually get it to work now. Because I want to pair this with Lyx, I want to let `\assigntitle{4}` be call after `begin{document}`.

Comment: @Michelle: You made your decision already, (and unaccepted an already accepted solution, after editing your question), so no chance to improve my answer...

Answer (score 5):

It's a “chicken and egg” problem: with this code you must state `\assigntitle{4}` *before* `\begin{document}`.

An alternative and perhaps better strategy is to it with `\maketitle`:

```
\ProvidesClass{Assignment}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\newcommand{\@assignment}{Assignment \#}
\newcommand{\assigntitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\@assignment}{Assignment \#{#1}}}

\renewcommand\maketitle{%
    \begingroup % <----- don't forget this one
    \centering \huge \upshape \@assignment \\
    \normalsize \normalfont \@date
    \bigskip
    \endgroup % <----- matching \begingroup
}

\endinput
```

Now your sample document can be in any of the two forms below

```
\documentclass{Assignment}

\assigntitle{4}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{Assignment}

\begin{document}

\assigntitle{4}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

You can add `\date{July 28, 2016}` anywhere before `\maketitle`.

The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` tokens I added are necessary if you don't want `\centering` going on for the whole document.

If you still need `\maketitle`, use a different name for the command producing the header.

Note that typesetting material using `\AtBeginDocument` is not recommended, because several packages that a user might add after declaring the class do their business using that hook and so they would act *after* the header has been typeset.

Comment: Great idea redefining `\maketitle`.  The block surrounding`\centering` was removed (had other code in it) in an attempt for clarity, which now has it completely opened, so yes I will have that covered, but thanks for reminding me.